# Cannot Install ROS Electric Desktop-Full on Oneiric AMD64 - In Dependency Hell

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu, ros-electric, ubuntu-oneiric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
stephanie@WorkTime:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-electric-desktop-full : Depends: ros-electric-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.5-s1336543727~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-vision-opencv (= 1.6.13-s1336531637~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-perception-pcl (= 1.0.2-s1336532338~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-image-pipeline (= 1.6.4-s1336532075~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-simulator-gazebo (= 1.4.15-s1338549736~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-image-transport-plugins (= 1.4.2-s1336531748~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-navigation (= 1.6.5-s1336537141~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
stephanie@WorkTime:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-electric-slam-gmapping ros-electric-vision-opencv ros-electric-image-pipeline ros-electric-simulator-gazebo ros-electric-image-transport-plugins ros-electric-navigation
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-electric-navigation : Depends: ros-electric-perception-pcl (= 1.0.2-s1336532338~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libsdl-image1.2-dev but it is not going to be installed
 ros-electric-simulator-gazebo : Depends: ros-electric-perception-pcl (= 1.0.2-s1336532338~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
 ros-electric-vision-opencv : Depends: libopencv2.3-dev (= 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
stephanie@WorkTime:~$ sudo apt-get install libopencv2.3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libopencv2.3-dev : Depends: libtiff4-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
stephanie@WorkTime:~$ sudo apt-get install libopencv2.3-dev libtiff4-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libtiff4-dev is already the newest version.
libtiff4-dev set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libopencv2.3-dev : Depends: libjpeg62-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
stephanie@WorkTime:~$ sudo apt-get install libopencv2.3-dev libtiff4-dev libjpeg62-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libtiff4-dev is already the newest version.
libtiff4-dev set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjpeg-turbo8-dev : Conflicts: libjpeg62-dev but 6b1-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
stephanie@WorkTime:~$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43731/cannot-install-ros-electric-desktop-full-on-oneiric-amd64---in-dependency-hell/) by [Stephanie](https://answers.ros.org/users/3195/stephanie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-09-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like someone upgraded your Ubuntu oneiric install to precise (12.04 LTS) while you weren't looking.  Try installing fuerte's precise repo as described at http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas @ Uni](https://answers.ros.org/users/3198/thomas-@-uni/) with karma: 26 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3